# Filter records in outer join based on criteria

Tags: sql, join, filter, oracle11gr2

I have 2 simple tables as follows:-

```
 Student
 ---------------------------------------------
  student_id    student_name    student_class
     107           paul            A Level-I
     108           susan           Diploma
     109           jack            O Level-II 
 ---------------------------------------------

Student_Positions
--------------------------------------------------
 position_id      student_id    position    date
    1               107           1          1-1-2020
    2               107           1          1-1-2021
    3               109           2          1-1-2021
    4               109           1          1-6-2019
```

I want a left outer join on these tables for the latest position of every student as fol:-

```
 student_id    student_name     position       date
    107              paul          1          1-1-2021
    108             susan        
    109              jack          2          1-1-2021
```

I have made multiple tries with different positions of max(date) and group by but in vain.
Please help with correct query

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical SQL solution uses a window function such as `row_number()`:

```
select s.*, sp.position, sp.date
from students s left join
     (select sp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from student_positions sp
     ) sp
     on sp.student_id = s.student_id and sp.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Actually i need to create a view. Can i try this query in view too?

Comment: @jaykio77 . . . Yes, just put `create view <viewname> as` before the `select`.

Comment: accepted your answer. can you please guide me. i know simple sql. but in order to create queries under discussion, which book or online reference should i read

Comment: @jaykio77 . . . I'm the wrong person to ask, because I am biased to my own books.  You can investigate at your favorite online bookseller.